# Accessing SQLite DB in multiuser app in Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I've a requirement to access database created by a system user from other service via a foreground user. Both services are part of the same application.

Created a system service, which creates a database and exposes it via ContentProvider. In another application, foreground user tries to access it via ContentResolver.

Added permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
```

manifest declarations

```
<service
android:name=".EXDBService"
android:enabled="true"
android:singleUser="true"
android:exported="true" />

<service
android:name=".EXService"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="true"
android:permission="com.example.EX_SERVICE" />
<provider
android:name=".EXDBMananger"
android:authorities="com.example.provider"
android:exported="true"
android:readPermission="com.example.provider.READ_DATABASE"
android:writePermission="com.example.provider.WRITE_DATABASE" />
```

But when making the request like insert/update with Contentresolver, it is throwing an error couldn't open database.

```
ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
Uri uri = DbContract.BASE_CONTENT_URI;
// initiate contentValues with valid data
Cursor cursor = resolver.insert(uri, contentValues);
```

Wish I could share more code here, but any guesses for what this could cause this issue?

I saw the user id 11 trying to access database on other application which is running on user 0. Does this cause any permission issue?

```
2023-04-20 21:01:48.745 8530-8530/com.example.xxxxx E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.xxxxx/databases/My.DB'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database '/data/data/com.example.xxxxx/databases/MY.DB': Directory /data/data/com.example.xxxxx/databases doesn't exist
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:254)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:205)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:505)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:206)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:198)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:919)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:899)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:763)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:752)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:383)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:340)
```

Comment: *it is throwing an error couldn't open database.* - please share the stacktrace

Comment: edited the question to add stacktrace. 
`Directory /data/data/com.example.xxxxx/databases doesn't exist`
Actually Directory exists, looks like permission issue, not sure what permission that is.

Comment: `chmod 777 /data/data/com.example.xxxxx/databases/*` ?

Comment: Why would there be a permission issue when reading through contentresolver? Why we need to do this manual step to give permission to the db folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the issue with manifest tag sharedId, removing which resolved the issue. Also here's how the application looks like after the problem is solved. Hopefully this helps.

[image]